# Sending Data in dictionary in form of x-www-form-urlencoded but it expects JSON

Tags: ios, json, objective-c

I sent my data as url-encoded form:

```
JobId=564876565946&UstaId=242816809697&Comment=&Ratings=%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20QuestionId%20%3D%203533%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Rating%20%3D%204%3B%0A%7D%2C%7B%0A%20%20%20%20QuestionId%20%3D%209767%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Rating%20%3D%205%3B%0A%7D%5D
```

When I decode this data:

```
JobId=564876565946&UstaId=242816809697&Comment=&Ratings=[{
    QuestionId = 3533;
    Rating = 4;
},{
    QuestionId = 9767;
    Rating = 5;
}]
```

It is shown as above,
but in postman it was successful when I sent in this form:

```json
{
    "JobId": 564876565946,
    "UstaId": 242816809697,
    "Ratings": [
        {
            "QuestionId": 3533,
            "Rating": 4
        },
        {
            "QuestionId": 9767,
            "Rating": 4
        }
    ],
    "Comment": "test postman"
}
```

In the JSON format.

The parameters that I created are created like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                        @"Ratings":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",[self.ratings componentsJoinedByString:@","]],
                        @"Comment":comment,
                        @"UstaId":[self.ustaID stringValue],
                        @"JobId":[self.jobID stringValue]
};
```

And I add my answers to the `self.ratings(which is a NSMutableArray)` as like this:

```
for(RatingQuestion * question in AppDlg.reviewQustions){
    self.answer=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [self.answer setObject:[question.ID stringValue]forKey:@"QuestionId"];
    [self.answer setObject:@5 forKey:@"Rating"];
    [self.ratings addObject:self.answer];
}
```

The code is written in Objective-C for iOS and I can provide more information when requested.

I want my URL encoded data sent correctly.

Comment: Your question is unclear. But `@"Ratings":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",[self.ratings componentsJoinedByString:@","]]` seems a lot wrong to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prepare a JSON request, you would use [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization/).

But, first, I would advise not using `stringValue` when building your array of ratings. You want numbers as `NSNumber`:

```objectivec
self.ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (RatingQuestion *question in reviewQuestions) {
    [self.ratings addObject:@{
        @"QuestionId": question.ID,
        @"Rating": question.rating,
    }];
}
```

Then, you want to build JSON, just put your `ratings` (an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`) in the `params` dictionary (and, again, avoiding `stringValue` for `ustaID` and `jobID`):

```objectivec
NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"Ratings": self.ratings,
    @"Comment": self.comment,
    @"UstaId": self.ustaID,
    @"JobId": self.jobID
};
```

Then, to build the JSON, use `NSJSONSerialization`:

```objectivec
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (!json) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

Now, you can use that `json` however you want. For example, you likely want to set the `HTTPBody` of an `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```objectivec
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = json;
```

If you want to confirm that the JSON is what you expected (for debugging purposes), you can also create an `NSString` of that `NSData`:

```objectivec
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Which will output:

```json
{
  "JobId" : 564876565946,
  "UstaId" : 242816809697,
  "Comment" : "test postman",
  "Ratings" : [
    {
      "QuestionId" : 3533,
      "Rating" : 4
    },
    {
      "QuestionId" : 9767,
      "Rating" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Note, above I used the [`NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonwritingoptions/nsjsonwritingprettyprinted?language=objc) option. Once you have confirmed that the JSON is what you want, you can use `0` or `kNilOptions` instead. But pretty-printed format is useful when visually inspecting the JSON for correctness.

---

Note, the reason we make sure our `NSDictionary` has numeric values as `NSNumber` rather than `NSString`, is that `NSJSONSerialization` will put quotation marks around strings, but not around numeric values. Your Postman sample did not have quotation marks around the numeric values, so I assume you did not want your Objective-C code to introduce quotation marks, either.